# How do I make a SKSpriteNode avoid another SKSpriteNode?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, game-physics

I am working on an AI mode for a SpriteKit game I am making in Xcode. I have dynamic physics bodies which can be launched towards the AI. I want to make it so that when one of these bodies is within a certain radius of the AI, the AI tries to dodge it. I have started working through different routes and got decent results.

1st method (pseudocode): Check AI.position.x and AI.position.y and compare to incomingSprite.position.x and incomingSprite.position.y. Break this comparison into quadrants if both x and y are within radius. (i.e. incomingSprite is bottom left relative to AI, bottom right, etc). Based on this info move the AI's position to move away from it.

cons: 
-lots of code and calculations in update function to account for multiple incoming sprites
-depending on dx and dy of incoming sprite, the AI often make illogical decision

2nd method (pseudocode): Calculate distance from AI to incomingSprite. Then check dx and dy of incomingSprite and set dx and dy to go in reverse direction of incomingSprite. This seems logical. I am a little rusty on reversing vectors to do this. I feel like this might be possibly a good idea though.

Is there a better method to accomplish this? Perhaps a force field on the magnet I could use to repel the AI at a certain strength so that if the incomingSprite is fast enough it will override and still collide anyway? Im concerned about memory as most of the AI logic is in the update function, which can cause big problems if I'm not careful.

Edit: I decided to use the electric field and gave the incoming sprites a positive charge so that they are repelled by the AI. This makes things accurate/lightweight and more interesting. If the incoming sprites are fast enough, they will break through the electric field and still collide with AI. This also gives room as an additional difficulty parameter in my game (the stronger the field, the harder it is to get the incoming sprites to collide with the AI).

Comment: Please take a look of GameplayKit - GKBehavior :) 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gameplaykit/gkbehavior
https://www.raywenderlich.com/706-gameplaykit-tutorial-entity-component-system-agents-goals-and-behaviors